# What is the branch of philosophy concerned with such questions?

Tags: death, life

What is the branch of philosophy concerned with questions like:

---

- If we're going to forget why do we learn?
- If we're going to die why do we struggle for?
- If we're going to die, is "happiness" a bogus word?
- Why do we want to learn?
- Do the questions above make sense?

---

And who should I read to dig in these(any suggestion on some philosophers)?

Comment: Is there any chance you could focus in one particular question? This is pretty broad as written, but could be an interesting series of questions if you narrowed it down a little bit (e.g., *Which philosophers write about motivation?*)

Answer (score 1):

Ethical or moral philosophy. Maybe read about the Epicureans and Stoics.

Comment: you mean after that no one thought deeply and wrote about these? been more than 2000 years

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally the branch of philosophy which dealt with these questions was called [Axiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology), which included ethics, aesthetics (the philosophy of art and beauty), and the overall question of happiness. Axiology was arguably the central topic of the philosophy of Plato, Aristotle, The Epicureans, and the Stoics, and most of the Classical philosophers.

Contemporary philosophers tend to speak not just of Axiology, but of [Value Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/value-theory/), which would include not only the traditional questions of Axiology, but also economics and social perspectives on the question of value. [Critical Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-theory/) and [theories about justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Theory_of_Justice) can also be concerned with the questions you brought up, although seen from a group perspective, not an individual one.